# Get value from multi-dimensional $_POST array

Tags: php, arrays, post

I'm trying to get value from the following $_POST array:

```
    [name] => Joy
    [adq12] => Array
            (
                ['qst'] => Yes
                ['ans'] => Occasionally
            )
    [lang] => Array
            (
                [0] => English
                [1] => Japanese
            )
```

When i try to `echo $_POST['lang'][0];` it is getting the output "English". But when i try to get the value from `echo $_POST['adq12']['ans'];` it is showing a notice error: `Notice:  Undefined index: ans in`. Anyone can help me please?

Comment: Can you show us your actual code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that the actual **key** is `'ans'`, (including the single-quote).

You should try:

`$_POST['adq12']["'ans'"]`

Comment: perfect answer...

Answer (score 2):

Since string keys are printed as `[adq12]`, it would appear that `['qst']` indicates that the quotes are part of the key. So: `$_POST["adq12"]["'qst'"]`.

Comment: adding single quotes within the double quotes did the magic, i really tired to find this...